# Populate and generate a pandas dataframe using conditions from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, one having individual data and the other dataframe is a configuration rule for the individual data. 
These are the dataframes:

df1:

```
  employee_Id first_Name  last_Name    email_Address   
0       E1000       Manas         Jani      jam@xyz.com
1       E2000         Jim         Kong      jik@xyz.com
2       E3000       Olila   Jayavarman      olj@xyz.com
3       E4000        Lisa     Kopkingg      lik@xyz.com
4       E5000     Kishore      Pindhar      kip@xyz.com
5       E6000        Gobi        Nadar      gon@xyz.com
```

df2:

```
  Input_file_name Is_key Config_file_name           Value
0     Employee ID      Y      employee_Id  idTypeCode:001
4        EntityID      N        entity_Id    entity_Id:01
```

I need my resulting individual dataframe to look like this,

Result_df:

```
employee_Id first_Name  last_Name    email_Address      idTypeCode  entity_Id
0       E1000       Manas         Jani      jam@xyz.com         001         01
1       E2000         Jim         Kong      jik@xyz.com         001         01
2       E3000       Olila   Jayavarman      olj@xyz.com         001         01
3       E4000        Lisa     Kopkingg      lik@xyz.com         001         01
4       E5000     Kishore      Pindhar      kip@xyz.com         001         01
5       E6000        Gobi        Nadar      gon@xyz.com         001         01
```

I am unable to understand how to get the `Value` column to the final dataframe.

Comment: Oh! So the configuration dataframe is a rule file which says that on the input file the column name is "Employee ID" but it should be "employee_Id" really. So it does not have an actual ID under it, if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not crystal clear. However I hope, this may help you.

First working on the first dataset to extract the values.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# test data
zz = """Input_file_name Is_key Config_file_name           Value
0     Employee ID      Y      employee_Id  idTypeCode:001
4        Entity ID      N        entity_Id    entity_Id:01
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)


extract = df['Value'].str.split(':',expand=True).transpose()
extract.columns = extract.iloc[0]
extract = extract.drop(extract.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(extract)

# 0 idTypeCode entity_Id
# 0        001        01
```

Then merging the two.

```
# test data
zz = """employee_Id first_Name  last_Name    email_Address   
0       E1000       Manas         Jani      jam@xyz.com
1       E2000         Jim         Kong      jik@xyz.com
2       E3000       Olila   Jayavarman      olj@xyz.com
3       E4000        Lisa     Kopkingg      lik@xyz.com
4       E5000     Kishore      Pindhar      kip@xyz.com
5       E6000        Gobi        Nadar      gon@xyz.com
"""
empl = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)

pd.concat([empl, extract], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=True).fillna(method='ffill')

#   employee_Id first_Name   last_Name email_Address idTypeCode entity_Id
# 0       E1000      Manas        Jani   jam@xyz.com        001        01
# 1       E2000        Jim        Kong   jik@xyz.com        001        01
# 2       E3000      Olila  Jayavarman   olj@xyz.com        001        01
# 3       E4000       Lisa    Kopkingg   lik@xyz.com        001        01
# 4       E5000    Kishore     Pindhar   kip@xyz.com        001        01
# 5       E6000       Gobi       Nadar   gon@xyz.com        001        01
```